# Sum & Product of Two Algebraic Numbers

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

If you have algebraic numbers $x$ and $y$, and you know the polynomials of least degree of which each is a solution (written as a vectors of coefficients), then how is the vector of coefficients of the polynomial of least degree of which $x y$ is a solution found; and likewise for $x+y$?

Comment: Absolutely _not_! I'm asking for a recipe for explicitly computing the vector of coefficients of the polynomial is a solution - _not_ for a proof that it exists.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark -- However ... now that I look at _the answers_ more carefully, I see that there is one that _might possibly_ give the solution. So thankyou for signposting it for me. I'm not sure it _does_ give the answer yet ... but it kindof _looks like_ it might.

Comment: The accepted answer definitely says how to do it. (You have to look up how to compute resultants, and the formulas that you get aren't going to be simple, but that's just how it is.)

Comment: And anyway the *question* is a duplicate, since that other question also asks for an *explicit formula* for a polynomial having $xy$ or $x+y$ as a root.

Comment: @Hans Lundmark -- I do think I might be able to extract a solution (or maybe even more than one!) from it. It's _extremely_ interesting post! But I could do with something abitt more explicit & _specifically tuned_ to my question. Like ... what's this _resultant_? But at least that gives me a _handle_ on it that I didn't previously have.

Comment: You can find a definition of the resultant function [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) which tells you how to compute it, but note that it gives you a polynomial which is a product of what you want, so it might not be the actual minimal polynomial. Say if $xy$ has degree lesser than the product of the individual degrees, or if $x,y$ are not algebraic integers. For example if $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $y=3\sqrt{2}$ you're going to get a linear polynomial. However if you expand out the functions it's actually an explicit function (of sums and products).

Comment: @Yong Hao Ng -- Please kindly accept my thanks for that signposting. I've got a _handle_ on the matter, now, certainly ... but I can see that it's not as simple as just having someone _dispense_ me ___the answer___! But what you said about the method of 'resultants' yielding a _linear_ polynomial in the case of x=√2 & y=√3 !!? _That_ doesn't seem so good on the face of it! But the 'ball is in _my_ court' now, as is said ... & I'm not expecting anyone to serve me a real-time coaching to the extent of ironing-out every wrinkle for me!